# How to add foreign fields from another database table into a treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, search, treeview

A-level student here. Sorry if this is a question with an obvious answer, I think I have just met a mental block.

I am trying to add `Firstname` and `Lastname` from my `Client` table into a Tkinter Treeview of my `Jobs` Table as part of search mechanism for my database. I can display them in a standard Treeview of the database, but when I search for a specific Client in the `Jobs` table I wish to display their First and Last names as well.

As `Firstname` and `Lastname` belong to only the `Client` Table I am using a query to get and display on the Treeview, however I can't find a method of it working for the search.

Here below if the code for my Search mechanism (Sorry for the sloppiness!)

```
 def SearchTable(self,tableName,column,NameEntry,tree,tableNo):
        valid = True
        e = str(NameEntry.get())
        for ch in e:
            if tableNo == 1:
                if ch.upper() not in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-":
                    valid = False
            if tableNo == 2:
                if ch not in "1234567890/":
                    valid = False
            if tableNo == 3:
                if ch not in "1234567890":
                    valid = False
        if not valid:
            NameEntry.config(bg="red")
            showerror("Planar Pete Error!","Error! Please retype your entry")
            NameEntry.delete(0,END)
            NameEntry.focus_set()
            NameEntry.config(bg="white")
        conn = sqlite3.connect("PlanarPeteVes2.db")
        curse = db.cursor()
        print(e)
        
        #curse.execute(f"SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM Client WHERE ClientNo = 1")
        #result = str(curse.fetchall())
        #FLName = self.ProcessString(result)
        #print(FLName)
        
        curse.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {column} = '{e}'")
        result1 = str(curse.fetchall())
        #allOfTable = self.ProcessString(result1)
        
        
        #result = str(FLName)+str(allOfTable)
        #print(result)
        count = 0
        
        for row in result1:
            if tableNo == 1:
                disp=(f'{row[0]} {row[1]} {row[2]} {row[3]} {row[4]} {row[5]} {row[6]} {row[7]}')
                tree.insert("",count,text="", values=disp)
                count +=1
            elif tableNo == 2:
                disp=(f'{row[0]} {row[1]} {row[2]} {row[3]} {row[4]}')
                tree.insert("",count,text="", values=disp)
                count +=1
            elif tableNo == 3:
                disp=(f'{row[4]} {row[5]} {row[6]}')
                tree.insert("",count,text="",values=disp)
                count +=1
               
        return NameEntry
```

All the `#` are code I have used to try and solve the issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! thank you :]